# Can I run driver.get() with different URLs in one script?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am pretty new to coding and web-scraping. One thing that I noticed is when I open up a browser with url_1 and scrape URLs for other categories let's say, and then try to proceed to opening them with the same driver.get(_new_url) nothing happens and the browser shuts down. However, if I assign webdriver.Chrome(PATH) to a new variable name, new_driver for example I can proceed with new_driver.

Anyone could explain me why this happens and how this bit works? Am I meant to create a new driver object every single time for every single new link?

So this is how I basically got the code to work, however I would like to know why I need to create a new driver object every single time?

```
main_page = 'https://www.*******.com/gaming'
PATH = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get(main_page)

sub_categories = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'list-nav- item.context-nav-link')

links = []

for el in sub_categories:
    links.append(el.get_attribute('href'))

new_driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
new_driver.get(links[0]) #going to 1st link obtained
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have collected the value of *`href`* attributes within the list *links*, you can open them all as follows:

```
main_page = 'https://www.********.com/gaming'
PATH = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get(main_page)
sub_categories = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'list-nav-item.context-nav-link')
links = []
for el in sub_categories:
    links.append(el.get_attribute('href'))

for link in links:
    driver.execute_script("window.open('" + link +"');")
```